# Chrome Extension - How to execute a JS script on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The following is that I'm trying to achieve

Every time 'www.google.com' loads, a script/function triggers. However, the functions itself reloads the page via 'location.reload();'
Basically, an infinite loop of reloads.
Script reloads page -> Script injected -> Script reloads page -> etc.

I want the tab @ google.com to keep refreshing while I work/browse the net via other tabs in the same Chrome browser Window.

How should I approach this. I've been looking into background and content scripts but I'm stuck. Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I this this is impossible with inject scripts, due to how Chrome handles JavaScript on inactive tabs.  Chrome "pauses" (or rather minimalism the use?) of JavaScript while the tab is inactive.

Comment: That's what we have chrome.alarms for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you have no problem getting a content script to run **once** on page load.  I'm not going to help you with that...

You're going to have to

- have the content script send a message to the background script
- use `chrome.alarms.create(string name, object alarmInfo)` in the background script
- listen for the onAlarm event
- use chrome.tabs.sendMessage() to send a message to make the content script reload the page

This is, of course, totally untested!